# User Impersonation in a High Trust SharePoint App using the client-side object model

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

As I understand it, high trust apps have the ability to impersonate a user ([link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/01/31/configuring-sharepoint-on-premise-deployments-for-apps.aspx)):

> The app is considered high-trust because it is trusted to use any user
>   identity that the App needs, because the App is responsible for
>   creating the user portion of the access token.

My question is, how do I actually do this - create the access token based on an arbitrary user?

The reason I want to do this is that I want to create/modify a list in the My Site of a small number different users, when another user is executing the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TokenHelper methods for S2S have a parameter of type System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity. Pass in the identity you wish the request to execute under. If you pass null, then it is an app-only request.